# In or-tools, VRPTW, how to express the mutually exclusive relationship of nodes and use the penalty value to control the selection result of nodes

Tags: python, or-tools

python 3.6, or-tools 9.3.10497

I want to describe a mutually exclusive relationship between multiple nodes, that is, if some nodes are selected, other some nodes cannot be selected. At the same time, the selection of nodes is affected by the penalty value of dropping nodes. The decision will tend to select the node with a large penalty value and drop the node with a small penalty value.

For example, node A and node C belong to a mutually exclusive relationship, node B and node C belong to a mutually exclusive relationship.This means either select nodes A and B, or select node C.

I used two methods to achieve this mutual exclusion relationship, the code is as follows:

```
# Method One
routing.solver().Add(routing.ActiveVar(manager.NodeToIndex(node_a)) + routing.ActiveVar(manager.NodeToIndex(node_c)) <= 1)
routing.solver().Add(routing.ActiveVar(manager.NodeToIndex(node_b)) + routing.ActiveVar(manager.NodeToIndex(node_c)) <= 1)
```

```
# Method Two
indices = [manager.NodeToIndex(node_a), manager.NodeToIndex(node_c)]
routing.AddDisjunction(indices, 0, 1)
indices = [manager.NodeToIndex(node_b), manager.NodeToIndex(node_c)]
routing.AddDisjunction(indices, 0, 1)
```

Then I use `routing.AddDisjunction` to control the penalty value of the dropping node, trying to control the selection result of the nodes, like:

```
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node_a)], 10)
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node_b)], 10)
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node_c)], 21)
```

I tested different node arrangement orders, different penalty value size relationships, and different `FirstSolutionStrategy`. And I found that the selection of nodes is related to the arrangement order of nodes, controlling the size of the penalty value is unable to achieve the global optimal (least) penalty value.

I plotted the test results into the tables, it includes different `FirstSolutionStrategy`, the arrangement order of the nodes, the multiple relationship of the penalty value of the nodes (the actual penalty value is an integer), and the final selection result of the nodes.

[image]

[image]

Please give me some help or advice, thanks.